# Why is the child div offset?

Tags: html, css

There is something very basic about CSS that I seem to be missing. Consider ([CodePen](https://codepen.io/mgoldenb/pen/XWeJeey)):

```css
/* Reset */
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-block-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
}

.parent {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 3rem;
  border: 3px solid green;
}

.child {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 3rem;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Given that there are no paddings or margins, what is the narrow white space between the two borders?

Comment: because the child component is displayed in the content box of the parent. The border wraps the content box so the child will always be displayed inside.

Comment: There you go: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model

Comment: I don't understand. Could someone please expound in the reply? Also, this question may be basic, but is it bad? I did perform searches, but nothing came up...

Comment: You literally just have to read the docs on the link I attached :)

Comment: *I would expect the two borders to coincide.* --> where did you read it should be case? nothing overlap padding,margin or border in normal flow

Comment: They are forced to the exact same width and height. How would the child div be inside the parent div if both have the same size?

Comment: I think that is just a browser render issue. On the codepen you attached, there is no white space unless you zoom in on the browser.

Comment: Assuming the issue is the narrow white-space between the two borders in your screenshot, I don't see that space with your CodePen example in Firefox 94. Which browser are you using?

Comment: For example, if you check it on Chrome, you will get the same result. On Firefox 94 you won't see that.

Comment: Probably just a rounding/render issue in the browser.  If you set the border-width to an even number, the white space disappears (At least in Chrome).

Comment: @CornelRaiu True it seems to be a rounding error when zooming in. Having cross-browser mobile-first pixel-perfect layouts is hard enough without taking browser zoom into consideration. 

Comment: Try different zoom levels, you will probably find the white space coming and going even on Chrome. It's a 'part CSS' pixel (but a screen pixel) left behind when the system tries to match fractions of CSS and screen pixels.

Comment: @AHaworth exactly. CSS part pixel issues are really nice to handle - NOT -

Comment: @AlwaysLearning let's just say it got better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This clearly is a rendering bug in Chromium-based browsers, as I was able to reproduce the issue both in Chrome and Edge at 250% zoom level, and in the code pen also at 125% zoom level (current stable version, MacOS 12.0.1, ARM).

I've raised an issue in the chromium bug tracker: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1275530