# How to fully fill child div in div with borders in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem. I need to fill image in div with borders, but in Chrome 96.0 i see some inside margins from top and left, and don't know how to delete them.

This is my code:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  border: solid 2px red;
  padding: 0;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="img"></div>
</div>
```

What I see:

[image]

What my friend sees in Safari:

[image]

Comment: I'm using Chrome 96, and when I run your code snippet it looks fine to me. What are you seeing when you inspect the element?

Comment: I ran it on windows 11, maybe it is a bug only for those platform. I see it https://i.imgur.com/WwF3tcn.png

Comment: Ok, it looks like this problem and it is a bug. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70182543/why-is-the-child-div-offset

Comment: Seem like the effect you would get it your browser zoom level is set to 50%.  Make sure it's set to 'actual size'

Answer (score 0):

I think it is rounding related issue: https://johnresig.com/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/

It becomes clear when you change zooms levels.

As workaround we can set inset shadow on wrapper:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  border: solid 2px red;
  padding: 0;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
  margin: 0;
}

.shadow{
  /* add inset shadow to cover white gaps*/
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px red inset;
 }
```

```html
Normal output:
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="img"></div>
</div>
<br>
With inset shadow:
<div class="wrapper shadow">
  <div class="img"></div>
</div>
```